# twisted.web.client HTTP logging

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

How can I log the HTTP requests and responses when using `twisted.web.client`? I've checked the docs and sources and didn't find anything but maybe it's possible using some custom agents or some such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this, but you can implement your own [`IAgent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.web.iweb.IAgent.html), that does logging and delegates to another `IAgent`, perhaps using [`proxyForInterface`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.python.components.html#proxyForInterface).